# Hide Tabs Heading with Angular UI / Bootstrap UI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm struggling to hide the heading from tabs created using Angular UI.

For my solution I need to set the buttons of the tab in the header and the contents in another container on the page.

I need to hide the tab buttons rendered by the directive.

Any idea?

```
<div id="menuTabs">

<div ng-class="{menuTab: true}" data-ng-click="tabActiveMenu1 = true">Menu1</div>
<div ng-class="{menuTab: true}" data-ng-click="tabActiveMenu2 = true">Menu2</div>
<div ng-class="{menuTab: true}" data-ng-click="tabActiveMenu3 = true">Menu3</div>
<div ng-class="{menuTab: true}" data-ng-click="tabActiveMenu4 = true">Menu4</div>

</div>

<div data-tabset id="menuTabs">
<div data-tab data-active="tabActiveMenu1">
<div data-tab-heading data-ng-class="{hide:true}"></div>        
    Content1
</div>
<div data-tab data-active="tabActiveMenu2">
    <div data-tab-heading data-ng-class="{hide:true}"></div>        
    Content2
</div>
<div data-tab data-active="tabActiveMenu3">
    <div data-tab-heading data-ng-class="{hide:true}"></div>        
    Content3
</div>
 <div data-tab data-active="tabActiveMenu4">
    <div data-tab-heading data-ng-class="{hide:true}"></div>        
    Content4
</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are asking here. Are you trying to make the tab button completely disappear? Or are you trying to hide the heading of the web page? In any case, it sounds like ng-hide, ng-show, ng-if, and (if you still want the button to be shown, just diabled) ng-disabled. I highly recommend looking into those directives.

Comment: Hi, thanks for supporting me. With the html that I've posted I would have two buttons to activate the contents. The first one is created be my inside of the element menuTabs and the second one will be rendered by the agnular ui tabs directive. I need to hide the second one and I don't know how to get access to it through parameters to add a class or any other workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide all but the active tab, you can do this in CSS with the following:

```
.nav>li>a {
  display: none;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
  display: block;
}
```

## [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/OMRh4mPN0dWlcuMYvC5P?p=preview)

If you want to remove all of the tabs, and just show the content, you could possibly edit the templates or use only the first rule above (so the tabs are always hidden active or not).

Comment: Thanks a lot! that gave me an idea. I was making this too complicated. I don't know why I couldn't add a css class to the element but finaly it worked at it should and I just did .my-menu-class>ul.nav-tabs{display: none}

Comment: Great.  If it answered your question, please mark it accordingly so others may benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I too was looking for  way to remove all the tab headers. Here's what I found was needed:

```
.nav>li>a,
.nav-tabs {
    display: none;
}
```

The second line was necessary to remove the solid line at the bottom of the tab headers